# Jetty Apache Camel - max headers size - 431 error

Tags: java, http-headers, apache-camel, jetty, apache-karaf

I have definied rest endpoint in apache camel (runs inside karaf) and I receive very large (>8500) header. Jetty throws 431 status code (Request Header Fields Too Large). Is there any possibility to avoid checking headers size (just temporary) or to change the limit? I use jetty like this:

```
restConfiguration()
        .component("jetty")
        .port("7777");


RestDefinition restDefinition = rest(REST_PATH)
    .consumes("application/json")
    .produces("application/json");

restDefinition.get("view2").to("direct:getView2");
```

There is this method

```
.clientRequestValidation(false)
```

...but it does not work

Comment: Obvious question, why are you abusing HTTP and not using it properly (eg: don't make giant query strings, but use POST/PUT/etc with a request body instead)?  Large headers like that are often rejected by many intermediaries as well (firewalls, load balancers, etc).  And are discouraged with HTTP/2 and HTTP/3.  (Many implementations cannot actually handle the nuances of that kind of header with HTTP/2)

Comment: I can do nothing with it. It does not depend on me. There is always a get and always with large header.

Comment: Karaf + camel is a complicated combination.  Please edit your question and add any details of your particular setup.  Eg: who is in control of your Jetty instance in that scenario (karaf? pax? camel? jetty-home? osgi-http-server? jetty-osgi-boot? etc)  How have you deployed those Jetty components/bundles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the `requestHeaderSize` option on the Camel jetty component, to set a higher value. See the docs at: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jetty-component.html

Since you use rest-dsl you can set component options via `componentProperty` on the `restConfiguration`. See the rest dsl docs at: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/rest-dsl.html

Answer (score 0):

If needed directly in your route the easiest way to configure the request header size is: (although I think it will affect the whole "jetty" component)

```
camelContext.getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent.class).setRequestHeaderSize(2000);
```